# Could not autowire

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I write some Rest app via spring ioc. But i cant solve this problem.
Here is my exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'angularController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.akifev.dao.ContactDao com.akifev.controllers.AngularController.contactDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.akifev.dao.ContactDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.akifev.controllers.AngularRun.main(AngularRun.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.akifev.dao.ContactDao com.akifev.controllers.AngularController.contactDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.akifev.dao.ContactDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.akifev.dao.ContactDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

My applicationContext.xml(all my dao classes is in "com.akifev.dao"):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.akifev.dao"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

    <mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}"/>
    <mongo:db-factory
        dbname="${mongo.dbname}"
        mongo-ref="mongo"
        />
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
         <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

One of my DAOs:

```
@Repository
public class ContactDao {
    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public void save(Contact contact) {
        mongoOperations.save(contact);
    }


    public Contact get(Long id) {
        return mongoOperations.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(id)), Contact.class);
    }


    public List<Contact> getAll() {
        return mongoOperations.findAll(Contact.class);
    }


    public void remove(Long id) {
        mongoOperations.remove(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(id)), Contact.class);
    }
}
```

My RestController:

```
@RestController
public class AngularController {
    @Autowired
    ContactDao contactDao;
    @RequestMapping("/hola")
    public String angularController(@RequestParam(value = "user", defaultValue = "user") String name){
        //code for add the entry to database
        return "added";
    }
}
```

I tried annotate it with @Qualifer but it is not use.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks you for attention.

Comment: Isn't @Repostory specific for spring data? is it taken by the auto scan? Can you try to switch that annotation to plain @Component?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem solved.**

Annotation which solved my problem is `@ImportResources`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that my Spring is a bit rusty, but you don't have your `ContactDao` defined in your beans anywhere.  You should define it:

```
<bean id="contactDao" class="com.akifev.dao.ContactDao" />
```

Adding it to the component scan would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an interface that ContactDao should implement. For example

```
interface DAO { 
void save(Contact contact);
Contact get(Long id);
...
}
```

and then autowire that interface in your controller.

```
public class AngularController {
@Autowired
DAO dao
}
```

Make sure you're also importing the right @Repository annotation also and you're next getting it mixed up with something else

Comment: Again this exception. I think spring is not see springContext.xml but idk why.I put it at resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

there is no bean like mongoOperations declared in .xml, try update the repository DAO with

```
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Answer (score -1):

use @Component("contractDao") tag on class ContractDao.